# Thingsboard NodeMCU

Tags: nodemcu, thingsboard

I have connected the NodeMCU with the temperature sensor and sending the temperature data to the thingsboard, when sending locally ( thingsboard server running on localhost and NodeMCU connected to the same network )its being sent correctly but when sending the data remotely to a system where the thingsboard is running the data transfer fails
 By using tunnelling service of ngrok ( command as ngrok http 8080 ) which is converting the localhost to its IP as  http://448133bf.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8080 ( my thingsboard is running here )  and giving this http://448133bf.ngrok.io with the device token id at the nodeMCU its again fails to transfer the data
I have also tried converting the IP of my system as ( command as  ngrok http 192.168.43.167:8080 ) which is converting my system IP address as http://f9527176.ngrok.io -> http://192.168.43.167:8080 and giving this  http://f9527176.ngrok.io with the device token id at the nodeMCU, but it fails to send the data to thingsboard

Comment: nice, but we are here at Stack Overflow, not on Super User so show the code and the logs

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you have debugged the problem from an Hostname/ IP resolution point of view. I suspect this is either related to the port availability or network firewalls. Are you able to login to the OS that is hosting the thingsboard platform (ngrok) and see which ports are currently in use? (Ubuntu: sudo lsof -i -P -n)